R function stopped working after R update
I am really puzzled over this. I have been using an R package called "ggcyto". After some updates to R, the function stopped working by returning the following error when running the following code:
data(GvHD)
fs <- GvHD[1:3]
#construct the `ggcyto` object (inherits from `ggplot` class)
p <- ggcyto(fs, aes(x = `FSC-H`)) 


Error in guides$setup(scales, aesthetics, default =
params$guide_default %||%  :    attempt to apply non-function

I am really puzzled. I've done everything possible. I deleted R and R studio together with anything found under /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
I installed everything again and still, I get the same error. The code example I'm running is from the manual of the package so it should work. I'd appreciate any help very much.
Below is the output of sessionInfo()
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggcyto_1.18.0            flowWorkspace_4.2.0      ncdfFlow_2.36.0          BH_1.84.0-0              RcppArmadillo_0.12.8.4.0
[6] flowCore_2.2.0           ggplot2_3.5.1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.1    lattice_0.22-6      colorspace_2.1-0    vctrs_0.6.5         generics_0.1.3      stats4_4.0.3        base64enc_0.1-3    
 [8] XML_3.99-0.9        utf8_1.2.4          rlang_1.1.4         hexbin_1.28.3       pillar_1.9.0        glue_1.7.0          withr_3.0.0        
[15] aws.s3_0.3.21       Rgraphviz_2.34.0    BiocGenerics_0.36.1 RColorBrewer_1.1-3  plyr_1.8.9          jpeg_0.1-10         matrixStats_1.3.0  
[22] lifecycle_1.0.4     zlibbioc_1.36.0     RProtoBufLib_2.2.0  munsell_0.5.1       gtable_0.3.5        cytolib_2.2.1       labeling_0.4.3     
[29] latticeExtra_0.6-30 Biobase_2.50.0      parallel_4.0.3      curl_5.2.1          fansi_1.0.6         Rcpp_1.0.12         scales_1.3.0       
[36] BiocManager_1.30.23 S4Vectors_0.28.1    RcppParallel_5.1.7  graph_1.68.0        farver_2.1.2        deldir_2.0-4        interp_1.1-6       
[43] gridExtra_2.3       png_0.1-8           digest_0.6.35       dplyr_1.1.4         grid_4.0.3          cli_3.6.2           tools_4.0.3        
[50] magrittr_2.0.3      tibble_3.2.1        aws.signature_0.6.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3     data.table_1.15.4   xml2_1.3.3          httr_1.4.7         
[57] R6_2.5.1            compiler_4.0.3 

I updated many packages but I still get the same error:
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggcyto_1.26.4        flowWorkspace_4.10.1 ncdfFlow_2.44.0      BH_1.84.0-0          flowCore_2.10.0      ggplot2_3.5.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.12         BiocManager_1.30.23 plyr_1.8.9          pillar_1.9.0        compiler_4.2.3      cytolib_2.10.1      RColorBrewer_1.1-3  tools_4.2.3         zlibbioc_1.44.0     lattice_0.22-6     
[11] lifecycle_1.0.4     tibble_3.2.1        gtable_0.3.5        pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.1.4         graph_1.76.0        cli_3.6.2           Rgraphviz_2.42.0    hexbin_1.28.3       gridExtra_2.3      
[21] withr_3.0.0         dplyr_1.1.4         generics_0.1.3      S4Vectors_0.36.2    vctrs_0.6.5         stats4_4.2.3        grid_4.2.3          tidyselect_1.2.1    glue_1.7.0          data.table_1.15.4  
[31] Biobase_2.58.0      R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.6         XML_3.99-0.16.1     farver_2.1.2        RProtoBufLib_2.10.0 magrittr_2.0.3      scales_1.3.0        matrixStats_1.3.0   BiocGenerics_0.44.0
[41] colorspace_2.1-0    labeling_0.4.3      utf8_1.2.4          munsell_0.5.1 


Your code works on my R. Did you update ggplot2?

I updated one other package and that led to updating many others so ggplot2 could be among them. After that, I just removed everything and downloaded again but still no luck. Is there some systematic way I can troubleshoot this? Thanks!

You need to be more definitive re: "could be among them". The current version is 3.5.1.

sorry, you're right. I'm not sure which version of ggplot2 I was using. Oh, actually, could you please tell me the version of R and ggplot2 (3.5.1?) you are using? thanks!

The latest versions: (R 4.4.0 and ggplot2 3.5.1).

You can add to your question the output of sessionInfo(). That will give more hints to help you.

Your R version that is running is 4.0.3 from 2020.  It looks as though you have an old copy somewhere and that's causing the issues.

I think I am going to give up. I updated many packages (please see the sessionInfo() above) and I still get the same error. I have no clue what's causing this. I will just use ggplot2 for plotting instead :(

You may need to upgrade your R to the latest version. Have you tried that? Some packages may not run correctly on older versions of R.

R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) is the latest R version I could download on my Mac. For the latest version of R, I need to have a newer version of Mac operating system so I think I'm stuck with R 4.2.3.

I solved the problem by deleting the downloaded ggcyto package using BiocManager::install("ggcyto")under:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library

and downloading the macOS Binary (x86_64) version from:
https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggcyto.html
and copying it in the path above.
